# how can i use Instagram API to post a comment whenever a new post happens?

Tags: post, comments, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

i do need to make a comment when a new post get's posted and that comment should be on the new post .. i have never used Instagram so how can i simply do that ?

just like when the posts number get's increased post the comment on the latest post . [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdUFD.png)

Answer (score 0):

here is how i think it can be done but without API

we do need to click on the latest post first And have the cors allow extension First a set interval in the browser console then ajax to request the page that contains the posts number and then a regex to extract it and an if condition to compare the results then if the number isn't changed make it retry again after 45 sec ... and when the number gets changed we do a .click action on the next button to get the next  post then fill the text bar with the comment then .click action on the post button .

watch [this video to get an idea](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iWfz2RnTTaU) of what i am talking about and the source i got my idea from .